# Resolving angular.js in webStorm project

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

I followed the instruction on jetBrains to [Installing AngularJS Manually](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/using-angularjs.html).  1.4.x stable
Created a folder and drag it to the WebStorm icon on my El Capitan dock.
Right click on the folder and created a new file and named it index.html
Added the ng-app directive to bootstrap the application to the html element.

Trying to get the context assist to help resolve the link to angular.js file which is located as a sibiling to the folder I created in step 2 above but do not see it in the list after hitting ^Space twice.

[image]

So I just typed it by hand

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="/../angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

Name:    <input ng-model="username"/>{{username}}

</body>
</html>
```

But Chrome is showing the Binding with the expression inside it instead of evaluating it.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n6pa8o36/) works

```
<body ng-app>

Name:    <input ng-model="username"/>{{username}}

</body>
```

so my assumption is that your reference to angular.js isn't being loaded in the browser because it is incorrect. You will need to link to a [CDN for angular](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js) or place the angular.js file somewhere under your project directory. See the following for why External Libraries will not work as a reference. [WebStorm: How can I link the HTML to an installed JS library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383607/webstorm-how-can-i-link-the-html-to-an-installed-js-library)